# Callbacks with Python curses

Tags: python, callback, curses

I have code that looks like this:

```
stdscr.nodelay(1)
while True:
    c = stdscr.getch()
    if c != -1:
        stdscr.addstr("%s was pressed\n" % c)
    if time() - last > 1:
        stdscr.addstr("time() == %s\n" % str(time()))
        last = time()
```

However, I'm worried that my code is really wasteful/inefficient. Is there a callback mechanism available for curses? If not, what would be the canonical way to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) instead.

Urwid provides a higher-level toolkit on top of curses and includes an event loop to handle keyboard and mouse input. It either uses it's own select-based event loop, or can hook into gevent or Twisted.

In addition to handling keyboard input efficiently you'll also have a host of options to handle user input with edit boxes, list controls and more.

Answer (score 2):

How about using half-delay mode to make getch() blocking?

```
import time
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.halfdelay(10) # 10/10 = 1[s] inteval

try:
    while True:
        c = stdscr.getch()
        if c != -1:
            stdscr.addstr("%s was pressed\n" % c)
        stdscr.addstr("time() == %s\n" % time.time())
finally:
    curses.endwin()
```